# Manipulating with date functions in makumba (adding or substracting hours)

Tags: makumba

I want to get current date +/- some hours.

According to docummentation, one of those should work:

```
date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)
date_sub(current_time(), interval 1 hour)
```

but it doesn't. I use Makumba version is 0.8.2.5.1

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, these functions work only in Makumba >= 0.9 (and in some versions <= 0.7)

A workaround in 0.8 is to do the date programmatically via JSP tags, e.g.:

```
<jsp:useBean class="java.util.Date" id="oneHourAgo" />
<jsp:setProperty name="oneHourAgo" property="hours" value="${oneHourAgo.hours - 1}" />
```

and then use the variable inOneHour (which is in the pageContext) as a named parameter in your query, e.g.:

```
<mak:list from="company.Company c" where="c.TS_create >= $oneHourAgo">
  ....
</mak:list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the versions prior to 0.9 the `date_sub` and `date_add` functions don't get parsed correctly so they don't work properly. (it should actually be removed from the documentation)

In the version 0.9+ you'll have new functions `dateAdd` and `dateSub` and for your case you would do:

```
dateSub(now(),1,'hour')
```

and that should work.

Comment: Documentation at http://www.makumba.org/page/QueryLanguages#section-QueryLanguages-DateFunctions is updated